# xamarin.android unable to see public property of object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have a public property into

this class : **APIUserCredentials**

```
public class APIUserCredentials 
{
    private string _Email;
    private string _Password;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _Email; }
        set { _Email = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _Password; }
        set { _Password = value; }
    }

    public APIUserCredentials(string email, string password)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = password;
    }
}
```

I create the object in Oncreate of my Activity and I break on it. Visual Studio is unable to access the property password even if it's public. What is wrong ?

[image]

Take note: If I remove the getters & setters from my class APIUserCredentials like so :

```
public class APIUserCredentials 
{
    public string Email;
    public string Password;

    public APIUserCredentials(string email, string password)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = password;
    }
}
```

I can now access the property from the break. 
[image]

It looks like a compilator bug, but i'm not sure. Any help is appreciated! This same code is used on ios app and it works like a charm. But on Android, the accessibility doesn't work the same once I put getter and setter in my class APIUserCredentials.

Comment: Can you specify you build configuration? Maybe it's release optimisations that mask the fields/properties. Can you try in debug?

Comment: I am actually in debug config on a Nexus 6p

Comment: Can you add your .csproj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into Project Options/Android Options/Linking and set it to Sdk Assemblies Only and not Sdk and User assemblies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple xamarin.android demo and add an cs file named APIUserCredentials with the code just as yours. When I debug, it worked all right. I suggust you try creating a new project and try it. Or use "add watch" on the credentials. [image]